# How do I display Python dictionary data correctly in a Flask web page?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I'm training a CNN model by KERAS. I want to show the model's predict results in Flask web page.The trouble is that I want to return a dictionary data from my local python program and show the data in Flask web page, but I can't parse the JSON correctly and show the items by line. Because I have little knowledge in JS :(

I want the web page shows like this

```
笔迹最相似的5个书写人: 

top5_index[0] top5_prob[0]

top5_index[1] top5_prob[1]

top5_index[2] top5_prob[2]

top5_index[3]:top5_prob[3]

top5_index[4] top5_prob[4]
```

however the web page shows nothing...(I guess the JS part code went wrong)

There is my codes, and the it doesn't work.

python

```py
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file from post request
        f = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to ./uploads
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)

        # Make prediction
        top5_index, top5_prob = model_predict(file_path, model)

        wr_dict = {top5_index[0]:top5_prob[0], top5_index[1]:top5_prob[1],
                   top5_index[2]:top5_prob[2], top5_index[3]:top5_prob[3],
                   top5_index[4]:top5_prob[4]}

        return json.dumps(wr_dict)
    return None
```

JS

```
    // Predict
    $('#btn-predict').click(function () {
        var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
        $(this).hide();
        $('.loader').show();

        // Make prediction by calling api /predict/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/predict',
            data: JSON.parse(form_data),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                // Get and display the result
                $('.loader').hide();
                $('#result').fadeIn(600);
                $('#result').text(' 笔迹最相似的5个书写人: ');
                $('#value1').text(data[0]);
                $('#value2').text(data[1]);
                $('#value3').text(data[2]);
                $('#value4').text(data[3]);
                $('#value5').text(data[4]);
                console.log('Success!');
            },
        });
    });
```

How to change the JS part code to display the dictionary data in the correct format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flask.jsonify` for responses:

```py
import flask

return flask.jsonify(**wr_dict)
```

It does a bit more than `dumps`, according to the docs:

> This function wraps dumps() to add a few enhancements that make life easier. It turns the JSON output into a Response object with the application/json mimetype.

And on your JS end, you should `stringify` the data and not parse it (dict -> string), then parse the response (string -> dict):

```
// Make prediction by calling api /predict/
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/predict',
    data: JSON.stringify(form_data), // CHANGED HERE
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data); // CHANGED HERE
        // Get and display the result
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn(600);
        $('#result').text(' 笔迹最相似的5个书写人: ');
        $('#value1').text(data[0]);
        $('#value2').text(data[1]);
        $('#value3').text(data[2]);
        $('#value4').text(data[3]);
        $('#value5').text(data[4]);
        console.log('Success!');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @AdamGold :)

I tried your codes, however the web page didn't show the data. I checked the browser's console but it didn't report error, and codes in success: function(data) {} was not executed.

I guess it also fails to parse the data(return by flask.jsonify). Today I find a method to parse the JSONstring data correctly and display it in the web page. Still I use the json.dumps in my python file, and the dictionary is slightly modified. And in my file I change the code like this:

```
        ...
        # Make prediction
        top5_index, top5_prob = model_predict(file_path, model)
        wr_dict = {"index1":top5_index[0], "prob1":top5_prob[0],
                   "index2":top5_index[1], "prob2":top5_prob[1],
                   "index3":top5_index[2], "prob3":top5_prob[2],
                   "index4":top5_index[3], "prob4":top5_prob[3],
                   "index5":top5_index[4], "prob5":top5_prob[4]}

        return json.dumps(wr_dict)
    return None
```

```
    // Predict
    $('#btn-predict').click(function () {
        var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
        // Show loading animation
        $(this).hide();
        $('.loader').show();

        // Make prediction by calling api /predict
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/predict',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var data_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('.loader').hide();
                $('#result').fadeIn(600);
                $('#result').text('笔迹最相似的5个书写人:');
                $('#value1').text('编号及概率:'+data_obj["index1"]+'------'+data_obj["prob1"]);
                $('#value2').text('编号及概率:'+data_obj["index2"]+'------'+data_obj["prob2"]);
                $('#value3').text('编号及概率:'+data_obj["index3"]+'------'+data_obj["prob3"]);
                $('#value4').text('编号及概率:'+data_obj["index4"]+'------'+data_obj["prob4"]);
                $('#value5').text('编号及概率:'+data_obj["index5"]+'------'+data_obj["prob5"]);
                console.log('Success!');
            },
        });
    });
```

Thank you. I will learn more JS knowledge.